# Drawing a right triangle with loops

Tags: python, loops

I have spent the last half hour playing around and I still don't know how to make it so a character is added each time it loops. 
This picture can better explain it better of what I mean.

here's my code:

```
triangle_char = input("Enter a character: \n")

triangle_height = int(input("Enter triangle height: \n"))

for row in range(triangle_height):
    print(triangle_char)
```

[image: Result of my code]

Comment: You need to print a number of the character based on the row - a simple way is to multiply the character by the row: `print(triangle_char*(row)+1)`

Answer (score 1):

(My previous answer was not very well thought out, so edit:)

You just need to keep adding your `triangle_char` to a string. Start by declaring an empty string

```
string = ""
```

and then every iteration of the loop, add one character to it

```
string += triangle_char
```

For example:

```
triangle_char = input("Enter a character: \n")

triangle_height = int(input("Enter triangle height: \n"))

string = ""

for row in range(triangle_height):
    string += triangle_char
    print(string)
```

Will give you the result you are looking for

Comment: Ahhhh. I see.  Thank you! What a stupid mistake :/